# Not able to run nginx command in E drive windows 7, but able to run from C:\nginx\

Tags: nginx, windows-7

I have installed nginx in windows 7, location is C:\nginx. I am able to run nginx commands from this location, but not able to run nginx commands from another location. Set the system variable path as C:\nginx\nginx.exe, but still not able to run nginx command from other locations.

I have to run **nginx -c "E:\GitHub\central-frontend\nginx.conf" -p "E:\GitHub\central-frontend\dist"**
or **nginx -c "%cd%\nginx.conf" -p "%cd%\dist"** from the location **E:\GitHub\central-frontend\**

Now when I run this command from **E:\GitHub\central-frontend\** I am getting this error,

nginx : The term 'nginx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- nginx -c "%cd%\nginx.conf" -p "%cd%\dist"
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nginx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the system variable path to the nginx folder instead of the actual executable, i.e. `C:\nginx` instead of `C:\nginx\nginx.exe`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now. I referred this site https://www.vasos-koupparis.com/nginx-getting-started-install/ for nginx system path setting, there it is given as C:\nginx\nginx.exe.